# How do I write function to delay window load for 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to delay the action performed by the JavaScript code below, for 3 seconds. How do I do this?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function alertFunc() {
    const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
    loader.className += " hidden"; //class="loader hidden"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` function with 3000 as

```
 window.addEventListener("load", function alertFunc() {

        setTimeout(()=>{
        const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
        loader.className += " hidden"; //class="loader hidden"
        }, 3000)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function alertFunc() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
        loader.className += " hidden"; //class="loader hidden"
    }, 3000);
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout from javascript

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  console.log("Doc Loaded");
  setTimeout(callAfter3Second,3000);
});


function callAfter3Second(){
    console.log("3 second Waiting Done");
}
```